# Cannot open database requested by the login wpf sql

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am creating an application in WPF. The application is called St Johns and it is basically a bunch of text boxes that will save the details of a patient. So far I have got a database set up, text boxes and some background code. I'm currently experiencing an error which I believe it has something to do with the connection string. At the moment I'm am a newbie to C# and SQL Server.

The error states:

> cannot open StJohnsDatabase requested by the login. The login failed...

This is my source code. I have 5 text boxes and one button (`save_btn`):

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)            
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=True");

    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StJohnsDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";

    try
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO [patient] (PatientId , Firstname, Surname, Phonenumber, time) values(" + patient_id_tb.Text + " , ' " + firstname_tb.Text + " ' , ' " + surname_tb.Text + " ' , " + phone_number_tb.Text + " , ' " + time_tb.Text + " ' )";
        SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        con.Open();
        exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
 }
```

(btw I have had a long search on the internet and couldn't find/understand what was incorrect/how to fix this.)

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is correct ? As it seems the database is not allowing connections from the application pool you are running the application on.

Comment: ... and beware of [The Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: How can i test or find out what the connection string is?

Comment: Well as this is your local sql server - you need to have some kind of access. Either create a specific user that has access on your tables or give the application pool users permissions over it.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your connection string..

Always recomended to use parameterized query to avoid sql injection

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [patient] (PatientId , Firstname, Surname, Phonenumber, time) values (@PatientId,@Firstname,@Surname,@Phonenumber,@time)";
SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientId",patient_id_tb.Text);
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname",firstname_tb.Text);
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname",surname_tb.Text );
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber",phone_number_tb.Text);
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time",time_tb.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrated security means that your application is going to connect to your database as the currently logged in windows user. Does your current windows user account have a valid database log in, or do you log in using a specific username/password.

If you have a specific username/password, you'll have to specify them in your connection string:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StJohnsDatabase;User Id={username}; Password={password};Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was 100% to do with the connection string being incorrect.